# Uso correto de vírgula para isolar certos termos

Tags: ortografia, vírgula

Eu costumo isolar alguns termos por vírgulas em alguns contextos quando eles vão depois de "e" em uma oração. Segue abaixo os exemplos:

> Estou mal e, por isso, vou para o hospital.
>
> A vida é cruel e, consequentemente, é triste.
>
> O stackoverflow é uma fonte de conhecimento e, portanto, utilizá-lo é
>   benéfico.
>
> Pretendo estudar português e, com isso, obter conhecimento.

Como é possível perceber o uso de vírgulas segue um padrão. O que eu gostaria de saber é: estou certo ao escrever assim? O uso da vírgula nesses exemplos é facultativo?

PS: Sei como é o uso da vírgula com conjunções, a questão aqui é o seu uso em termos destacados que vem depois de "e". Portanto, o uso de vírgulas com conjunções não é a minha dúvida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, está correto tanto com ou sem vírgula, pois o uso de vírgula ao isolar advérbios ou locuções adverbiais é facultativo.

Isolar um advérbio por vírgula é completamente opcional.  O advérbio pode "flutuar" pela oração. E a vírgula é usada nesses casos geralmente como uma função estética (para indicar que o termo flutuante não é essencial à oração, e sem a vírgula o fluxo das palavras poderia não ficar óbvio) ou função semântica (para enfatizar a informação passada pelo advérbio).

Os exemplos a seguir ilustram como um advérbio pode flutuar numa oração.  A vírgula nesses casos é somente usada para enfatizar o fato de que o locutor tem certeza da vinda da chuva.

> A chuva virá amanhã, com certeza.
>
> Com certeza, a chuva virá amanhã.
>
> A chuva virá, com certeza, amanhã.
>
> A chuva, com certeza, virá amanhã.

Perceba que, nos dois últimos exemplos, a locução adverbial ocorre no meio da oração.  Nesses casos, a vírgula tem função estética, pois é "feio" ou "estranho" escrever "*A chuva com certeza virá amanhã*" (sem as vírgulas indicando a interrupção no fluxo essencial do texto), mas ainda assim esta frase está correta.

---

A conjunção **e** nos seus exemplos é um coordenador de orações, ela está separando duas orações diferentes (basta ver que antes do **e** há uma frase com um verbo e após há uma frase com outro verbo). Nos exemplos, o advérbio ocorre na segunda oração. O uso do **e** é completamente irrelevante para o uso da vírgula no caso da separação de advérbio (porém é relevante para o uso da vírgula para separar orações coordenadas, que também é opcional).

A seguir está um dos seus exemplos, com e sem algumas das vírgulas. Todas as frases abaixo são corretas e indicam a mesma coisa:

- "*Pretendo estudar português e, com isso, obter conhecimento.*" (aplicada a separação de locuções adverbiais).
- "*Pretendo estudar português, e com isso obter conhecimento.*" (aplicada a separação de orações coordenadas).
- "*Pretendo estudar português, e, com isso, obter conhecimento.*" (aplicadas a separação de orações coordenadas e a separação de locuções adverbiais).
- "*Pretendo estudar português e com isso obter conhecimento.*" (aplicada nenhuma separação).

[Nesta página](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/fono/fono30.php), o site soportugues.com.br fala o seguinte sobre separar advérbio/locução adverbial com vírgula:

> Obs.: a rigor, não é necessário separar por vírgula o advérbio e a locução adverbial, principalmente quando de pequeno corpo, a não ser que a ênfase o exija.

[Aqui](https://www.normaculta.com.br/virgula), o normaculta.com diz o seguinte:

> Pode isolar o adjunto adverbial no início ou meio da oração, sendo dispensável quando o adjunto adverbial for apenas um advérbio.
>
> - Calma e discretamente, ela lutou por seus direitos.
> - Ela, calma e discretamente, lutou por seus direitos.
> - Minha mãe jamais perdoará sua atitude.

[Em uma resposta](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-virgula-e-os-adverbios/30470) do site ciberduvidas, o usuário Pedro Mateus colocou citações da *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo*, uma excelente gramática da língua Portuguesa, sobre o uso de vírgula para separar advérbios.  Infelizmente não tenho acesso ao livro agora, somente o leio quando pego emprestado da biblioteca, e portanto não posso fornecer a citação completa da página em questão, mas quanto pegá-lo irei editar a resposta para colocar aqui. Mas entre no link para ver as citações que o usuário fez.